# Getting error You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am getting the below error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [An unknown error occurred attempting to fetch definitions at: https://sit-cscrm.cs12.force.com/auraCmpDef?aura.app=markup://c:CsRepView&_ff=DESKTOP&_l=true&_l10n=en_US&_style=undefined&_def=markup://c:CsRepMyContacts_Rep&_uid=LATEST-0] Failing descriptor: {ltng:outApp}"

when i click the load unsafe scripts then error is not coming and loading the page what could be the reason and how to resolve this issue?

**Controller.js**

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
   var selvalue='1';
     var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize");
    var action = component.get("c.getRepMycontacts");
    action.setParams({"selopt":selvalue});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var name = response.getState();
        if (name === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.con", response.getReturnValue());
            //add
            component.set("v.totalSize", component.get("v.con").length);
            component.set("v.start",0);
            component.set("v.end",pageSize-1);

            var paginationList = [];
            for(var i=0; i< pageSize; i++)
            {
             paginationList.push(response.getReturnValue()[i]);    
}

            component.set('v.paginationList', paginationList);
        }

    });

 $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
showreps : function(component, event, helper) {
   var selvalue = component.find("makeId").get("v.value");
    var action = component.get("c.getRepMycontacts");
    var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize");
    action.setParams({"selopt":selvalue});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var name = response.getState();
        if (name === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.con", response.getReturnValue());
            //add
            component.set("v.totalSize", component.get("v.con").length);
            component.set("v.start",0);
            component.set("v.end",pageSize-1);

            var paginationList = [];
            for(var i=0; i< pageSize; i++)
            {
             paginationList.push(response.getReturnValue()[i]);    
}

            component.set('v.paginationList', paginationList);
        }

    });

 $A.enqueueAction(action);

},
export : function(component, event, helper) {

    var data = component.get("v.con");
    console.log(data);
    // call the helper function which "return" the CSV data as a String   
    var csv = helper.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(component,data);   
     if (csv == null){return;} 

    // ####--code for create a temp. <a> html tag [link tag] for download the CSV file--####     
     var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
      hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
      hiddenElement.target = '_self'; // 
      hiddenElement.download = 'ExportData.csv';  // CSV file Name* you can change it.[only name not .csv] 
      document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement); // Required for FireFox browser
      hiddenElement.click(); // using click() js function to download csv file
    },

next : function(component, event, helper) 
{

    var conList = component.get("v.con");
    var end = component.get("v.end");
    var start = component.get("v.start");
    var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize");
    var paginationList = [];

    var counter = 0;
    for(var i=end+1; i<end+pageSize+1; i++)
    {
     if(conList.length > end)
        {
      paginationList.push(conList[i]);
            counter ++ ;
     }
    }
    start = start + counter;
    end = end + counter;

    component.set("v.start",start);
    component.set("v.end",end);

    component.set('v.paginationList', paginationList);
 },
previous : function(component, event, helper) 
{
 var conList = component.get("v.con");
    var end = component.get("v.end");
    var start = component.get("v.start");
    var pageSize = component.get("v.pageSize");
    var paginationList = [];

    var counter = 0;
    for(var i= start-pageSize; i < start ; i++)
    {
     if(i > -1)
        {
         paginationList.push(conList[i]);
            counter ++;
     }
        else
        {
            start++;
        }
    }
    start = start - counter;
    end = end - counter;

    component.set("v.start",start);
    component.set("v.end",end);

    component.set('v.paginationList', paginationList);
}


})
```

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"  access="global" controller="FetchRepMyContacts"><!--Server-Side/Apex Controller-->
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS252 +
         '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css'}"/>



<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<ui:inputSelect aura:Id="makeId" class="pickliststyle" multiple="false" label="Please Select Report Type: ">
        <ui:inputSelectOption label="Yesterday" text="1"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption label="Last 3 Months" text="2"/>

    </ui:inputSelect><br/><br/>
    <ui:button label="Show Report" class="buttonstyle"  press="{!c.showreps}"/>
    <ui:button label="Export Details" class="buttonstyle" press="{!c.export}"/>

    <br/><br/>
    <aura:attribute name="con" type="contact[]"/><!--List Of Contacts-->
    <!--add-->
    <aura:attribute name="paginationList" type="contact[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pageSize" type="Integer" default="8"/>
 <aura:attribute name="totalSize" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="start" type="Integer" />
 <aura:attribute name="end" type="Integer"/>
     <!--<ui:button label="Show Rep Contacts" press="{!c.myAction}"/>-->
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal" ><!--Table must be responsive-->
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading--label" >
                <th style="background-color: #ee3424;color: white" scope="col">Name</th>
                <th style="background-color: #ee3424;color: white" scope="col">Download Date</th>
                <th style="background-color: #ee3424;color: white" scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th style="background-color: #ee3424;color: white" scope="col">Email</th>
                <th style="background-color: #ee3424;color: white" scope="col">Website Downloads</th>                
            </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration var="q" items="{!v.paginationList}"><!--Dynamic Listing of Vehicles-->
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td data-label="Download Date" style="padding-left:0;">{!q.Name}</td>
                    <td data-label="Download Date" style="padding-left:0;">{!q.Download_Date__c}</td>
                    <td data-label="Phone" style="padding-left:0;">{!q.Phone}</td>
                    <td data-label="Email" style="padding-left:0;">{!q.Email}</td>
                    <td data-label="Account" style="padding-left:0;">{!q.Website_Downloads__c}</td>                
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
            <!-- add-->

             <lightning:button class="buttonstyle" label="Previous"     onclick="{!c.previous}"  /><!--disabled="{!v.start == 0}"-->
             <lightning:button class="buttonstyle" label="Next" disabled="{!v.end > v.totalSize}"  onclick="{!c.next}" />

            </tbody>
    </table>  
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the body of your post. You can format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or clicking `{}`.

Comment: when are you getting error?

Comment: @vasavi_sfdc -> you dont need to load SLDS in lightning, additionally, any reason why you are using `ui` namespaced components instead of `lightning`?

Comment: When first time login i am getting the error after clicking the load unsafe scripts in the browser then every thing is working what could be the reason

Comment: Hmm there is no any specific reason for adding ui namespace.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the salesforce spring release.
Add lightning component dependency in the lightning app.
`<aura:dependency resource="CsRepMyContacts_Rep"/>`